# prevent logback from rolling everyday

Tags: logging, logback

I am using logback framework (1.8) in my application, i set the rolling policy so that maximum file size is 5MB and it can stay for 10 days max with max total size of 100 MB, now everything works OK, but i noticed that a new log file is created every day regardless to the rolling policy, for example, yesterday, the latest log file was 10KB, when i came today and did some actions, the logging statement were added to a new log file and the latest one of 10KB was archived. do you have any idea how can i prevent this.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/opt/MoICT_Logs/IDM/IDM.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/opt/MoICT_Logs/IDM/IDM-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender> 
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jo.egov.portal" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">          
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you choose SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy you are asking to archive files by date and at the same time limiting the size of each log file.
So, if the date changes, the current log file will be archived (it's old, it refers to an old date) and a new file will be produced.
I think that for your purpose the FixedWindowRollingPolicy could be better: it doesn't define a rollback policy by date, so change of date doesn't have any effect. Moreover, you can choose how many files you want to archive and their size.